# NSMutable Array not covertible to [AnyObject] / NSMutableArray to type SKAction in coercion

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

```
var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(finalDestination, duration: NSTimeInterval(moveDuration)))
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

    torpedo.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as [AnyObject]))
```

error: 'NSMutableArray' is not implicitly convertible to '[AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

---

Second question because I can't post often which is very similar to the earlier issue:

```
var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alien.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.runBlock({
        var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        var gameOverScene:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won:false)
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: transition)
    }))


    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

    alien.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as [SKAction]))
```

### error:'NSMutableArray' to type '[SKAction]' in coercion

Not sure why I'm getting this but all these error's popped up since I switched to Xcode 7. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry should be... 1.

```
var actionArray:[SKAction] = [SKAction]()
actionArray.append(SKAction.moveTo(....
actionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
torpedo.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
```

2. `var actionArray:[SKAction] = [SKAction]()` ditto the rest

Comment: Hey thanks for the response,
I get this error:  Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to expected argument type '[SKAction]'